# Confusion regarding difference of machine learning and statistical learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

I have read these lines in one of the IEEE Transaction on software learning

"Researchers have adopted a myriad of different techniques to construct software fault prediction models. These include various statistical techniques such as logistic regression and Naive Bayes which explicitly construct an underlying probability model. Furthermore, different machine learning techniques such as decision trees, models based on the notion of perceptrons, support vector machines, and techniques that do not explicitly construct a prediction model but instead look at a set of most similar
known cases have also been investigated.

Can anyone can explain what they are really want to convey.
Please give example.

Comment: Isn't all summarized in _"...construct a prediction model **instead** look at a set of most similar known cases..."_. Let's imagine to pick a candy: in first case you collect its attributes, you feed a model and **calculate** a predicted result (similar to what you do when you model, for example, an electronic component and you _predict_ or _simulate_ its output). In second case you pick a candy and you **compare** with a well-known list of candies, when you find most similar one then you have your match and you know expected result.

Comment: I would venture that the difference is in the way the author understand those models. Another person could categorize them differently.

Answer (score 1):

The authors seem to distinguish probabilistic vs non-probabilistic models, that is models that produce a distribution `p(output | data)` vs those that just produce an output `output = f(data)`.

The description of the non-probabilistic algorithms is a bits odd to my taste, though. The difference between a (linear) support vector machine, a perceptron and logistic regression from the model and algorithmic perspective is not super large. Implying the former "look at a set of most similar known cases" and the latter doesn't seems strange.

Answer (score 0):

The authors seem to be distinguishing models which compute per-class probabilities (from which you can derive a classification rule to assign an input to the most probable class, or, more complicated, assign an input to the class which has the least misclassification cost) and those which directly assign inputs to classes without passing through the per-class probability as an intermediate result.

A classification task can be viewed as a decision problem; in this case one needs per-class probabilities and a misclassification cost matrix. I think this approach is described in many current texts on machine learning, e.g., Brian Ripley's "Pattern Recognition and Neural Networks" and Hastie, Tibshirani, and Friedman, "Elements of Statistical Learning".